# How to redirect to the landing page when the domain name is searched?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect

I recently learned how to clean my url by removing the ".php" or some other post and get variables in url, which is good. But then I'm having a problem with the landing page. Whenever I enter my website's url say for example: https://example.com, it should take me to https://example.com/index  which is the landing page in this case. I can't seem to get it right.

I tried changing my .htaccess file but didn't work and the code left there in .htaccess is just this :

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ router.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And in my router.php file I have this bunch of code which cleans up the url.
<?php

```
function split_url(){
    $url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : "index";
    $url = explode("/", filter_var(trim($url,"/"),FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

    return $url;
}
$root= $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] . "://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$root = trim(str_replace("router.php","",$root), "/");
define("ROOT", $root . "/");
$URL = split_url();
if(file_exists($URL[0].".php")){
    require($URL[0] . ".php");
}
else{
    require("404.php");
}
```

The problem is, when I go search my site's url ( https://example.com) it loads the page but it's empty and only if I search ( https://example.com/index) it takes me to the page with everything in it.
Please help me with this if there is another way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ router.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
> ```

It looks like you just need to set the `DirectoryIndex` to `router.php`. (The `DirectoryIndex` sets the file to serve when a directory is requested.) Because of the second *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) your existing mod_rewrite rule doesn't do anything for requests to the root directory (or any directory for that matter). This is why many front-controllers use `index.php`, which is the *default* `DirectoryIndex` document.

For example, at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex router.php
```

The above will result in `router.php` being looked for in any directory that is requested. So, request the root, it will look for `router.php` in the root. You could change this to a root-relative path that it will always serve `/router.php` (from the root directory) for whatever directory is requested. ie. `DirectoryIndex /router.php`.

It looks like your PHP script should then default to `index`.

Comment: And it worked! I don't know why I get stuck in places so simple like this. Thanks a lot :)